# Why Scala Future returns None using flatMap and for comprehension?

Tags: scala, future, reactive-programming

I have following Scala code, used with Scala 2.10

```
package reactive

import scala.concurrent.future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object futuresum extends App {

  def f1 = future { 12 }
  def f2 = future { 13 }

  val result1 = f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y))
  println(result1.value)

  val result2 = for (x <- f1; y <- f2) yield (x + y)
  println(result2.value)

}
```

This code should print `25`, but it prints `None`:

```
None
None
```

What is wrong with this code?

**EDIT**

This works for me now:

```
package reactive

import scala.concurrent.future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object futuresum extends App {

  def f1 = future { 12 }
  def f2 = future { 13 }

  val result1 = f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y))
  result1.onComplete(b => println(b))

  val result2 = for (x <- f1; y <- f2) yield (x + y)
  result2.onComplete(b => println(b))

  Await.result(result1, Duration.Inf)
  Await.result(result2, Duration.Inf)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll steal Régis Jean-Gilles' excellent answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358119/3328933

"Futures are executed on a dedicated thread pool. If your main program does not wait for the future, it will exit immediately and the future won't have a chance to execute. What you can do here is to use Await in your main program to block the main thread until the future executes:"

```
package reactive

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.future
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object futuresum extends App {

    def f1 = future { 12 }
    def f2 = future { 13 }

    val result1 = f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y))
    result1 onSuccess { case res => println(res) }
    Await.result(result1, 2 seconds)

    val result2 = for (x <- f1; y <- f2) yield (x + y)
    result2 onSuccess { case res => println(res) }
    Await.result(result2, 2 seconds)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that between the "result"s and its `println` the futures haven't had enough time to spawn/send-to their threads. Check this quick REPL session:

```
scala> f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y)).value
res2: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = None

scala> f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y))
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1c9dac55

scala> res3.value
res4: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Success(25))
```

Let's try something different:

```
scala> f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y)).onComplete(println(_))

scala> Success(25) // Press enter here. onComplete mixed with REPL output.
```

Another try:

```
scala> val later=f1.flatMap(x => f2.map(y => x + y)); later.onComplete(println(_)); println(later.value);
None
later: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@7019b737
Success(25)
```

Now that was a confusing output. It's a good illustration of my point, though:

1. First, create `later` which contains a computation that will be
   executed sometime in future.
2. Bind this computation with a event that will be triggered when it completes.
3. Print the result of the possibly unfinished computation.

Now think in two lines of execution. 1, 2 and 3 happens in the first, main line of execution, or the main thread. What lies inside the future, `{ 12 }`, `map`, `flatMat` happens in another line of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Use Await.result(result, duration) or Thread.sleep to wait future thread finish.
Then you can check future.isComplete to make sure that future is finished.

```
 Await.result(result2, 3 seconds)
 if(result2.isCompleted)
 println(result2.value)
```