# Using the Play WS API from pure Scala with sbt

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565475/possible-bug-in-scala-2-10-futures-do-not-run) it is said, that Scala future is represented as daemonic thread, so it shouldn't prevent the application to stop if the main thread is done.

However, if I run the following code:

```
object main extends App {
  println("before future\n*************")
  val responseFuture = WS.url("http://www.google.com").withRequestTimeout(5 * 1000).get
  responseFuture.onComplete[Unit](
    _ match {
      case Success(resp) => println(resp.body)
      case Failure(ex) => println(ex.getMessage)
    }
  )
  println(Await.result(responseFuture, Duration.Inf))
  println("after future\n*************")
}
```

I got following output, which is correct.

```
before future
*************
Response(com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponse@9913ac)
after future
*************
<!doctype html><html> ... </html>
```

But the program **keeps running** and I have to send a `SIGINT` to to terminate it. Why is the program not terminating? Do I have to close some connection explicitly? I guess, when using it directly from a Play project there is some automagic under the covers, but not in the normal Scala project.

**EDIT:**
jconsole says:

```
Name: main
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@14d0af4

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.take(ExecutorCompletionService.java:193)
sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:196)
...
```

---

### Env

**Scala version:** 2.10.2

**Java version:** 1.7.0_09-b05 (HotSpot)

**Play version:** "play_2.10" % "2.2.1"

**sbt version:** 0.12.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time you use the `WS` API, exactly one Ning `AsyncHttpClient` is created to actually do all the work for you.

You can see it all in the [WS source code here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala).

This client stays "alive" for the lifetime of the `WS` object, and I suspect it is that object that is grabbing the lock that prevents the main thread from finishing.

If you simply add:

```
WS.client.close()
```

at the end of your code snippet, the `AsyncHttpClient` terminates gracefully and the main thread exits.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Actually, I had to do this: `Await.result(responseFuture, 6 seconds)` and then `WS.client.close`. If I don't wait for the future and call it immediately, it doesn't work. It's pretty bad that I had to block the control flow.

I was trying also this:
`responseFuture onComplete {case _ => WS.client.close}` to my knowledge, it should work, but it doesn't :/

Comment: Because you're calling WS outside of Play, WS doesn't know when to shut itself down.  The underlying cause is the internal Netty thread pool used by AsyncHttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

You could also close the client by adding an onComplete callback.  This way you won't have to Await for the future.  FYI, Awaiting is bad!

```
responseFuture.onComplete {
 _ match {
  case _ => WS.client.close
 }
}
```

Comment: I was trying that, but it actually donesn't work, even though it should.